# React native app can't use axios to get data from .net server

Tags: .net, react-native, android-studio, axios, expo

I am trying to make a simple get to a local .net server using axios, for some reason it keeps throwing Network Error.

[this is the call i am trying to make](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h3fnt.png)

1 - I have tried replacing the url from localhost to my ip address and it still did not work.

2 - I have tried setting the cors to allow all origins.

[After adding cors and having my ip address instead of localhost if i run the app on the browser it is able to get the data from the api](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Asx6j.png)

But for some reason the emulator is unable to get the data and I have no idea why.

Comment: Use the same code and try it from a browser react app. Check browser developer tools network tab to see what's the error.

Comment: Tryed this, and it works fine on a web browser

Comment: Share the code that's calling the API and related.

Comment: how about using fetch ?

Comment: fetch gives me Network request failed